# How to use int argc,char *argv[] outside of main function in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I am having a problem when writing codes in c++. I used `int argc,char *argv[]` outside of the main function and it tells me they are not defined.
I have tried to use the `extern` but it doesn't help.
Can anyone please help me with this? Thank you!

```
extern int __argc;
extern char **__argv;
```

Comment: what is your objective?

Comment: You can pass them to the function(s).

Comment: Why downvoting this question without any comment? There are a lot of examples in the web which shows the usage of __argc/__argv which is not a standard at all.So it is normal to ask for that topic and the question is clear.

Answer (score 6):

Try either setting a global variable, or passing the values of `argc` and `argv` to your functions.

Method 1:

```
int argc;
char **argv;

void some_other_function() {
  std::cout <<  argv[0] << "\n";
}
int main(int ac, char **av) {
  argc = ac;
  argv = av;
  some_other_function();
}
```

Method 2:

```
void some_other_function(int argc, char **argv) {
  std::cout <<  argv[0] << "\n";
}
int main(int ac, char **av) {
  some_other_function(argc, argv);
}
```

Comment: @taocp WTH are you vandalizing this answer?

Comment: @H2CO3 Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Is it possible when I was editting, the answer was also being updated? I did not meant to make anything worse.

Comment: @taocp - It's all good now. You and I were editing simultaneously. I *think* I picked up your change -- highlight the variable names, right?